# *ngIf directives is not working in ionic 4

Tags: javascript, ionic3, angular7, ionic4

I'm trying to use `*ngIf` directive in ionic 4 with angular 7 projects. I'm facing the issue of `*ngIf` directive not work properly.
When I click the button it's not refresh view even condition is true.

```
<ion-grid *ngIf="!provider.loggedin">
```

view is shown this condition but when I login view is not changed

```
<div *ngIf="provider.loggedin" >
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your code, I guess.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, & give it a go. If you get stuck & can't get unstuck after doing more research & searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt & say specifically where you're stuck. Peeps will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: are you sure it's `loggedin` and not `loggedIn` or something?

Comment: Please share more of your code implementation. If *ngIf would be broken there would be a lot of hassle to get it fixed;)

Comment: Hi
Thanks for reply
i have resolved the issue , but i have some queries as i am new to angular and ionic.

hideLogin(res) {
 this.provider.loggedin = true;
}
   // first way that fails 
  loginWithGoogle = () => {
   const self = this;
   this.fire.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(res => {
    self.hideLogin(res);
   });

// second way , which works fine
     loginWithGoogle = async () => {
   const res = this.fire.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
   this.hideLogin(res);
}
can anyone explain , issue in first way.